# Move .git folder up in working tree hierarchy

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Yesterday I did one of these operations (see code snippet below) on my git repo in order to effectively move my project up a few folders in the folder hierarchy. This basically lists all files and adds a prefix folder name to them and updates the index accordingly.

#### Old layout:

```
+ Root
  - Sublevel 1
    - Sublevel 2
      - .git was here
```

#### New, desired layout:

```
+ Root
  - .git moved to here, so prefix all index files with "Sublevel 1/Sublevel 2/"
  - Sublevel 1
    - Sublevel 2
```

#### Command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
    git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t-&newRoot/sub1/sub2/-" |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE
    ' HEAD
```

However, this command, unbeknownst to me, only modified the `master` branch. I have about 8 other branches off of master. When I checkout one of these other branches, it checks out all files (some 11,000) in my repo in their original folder structure at the new root folder level where I moved the `.git` folder to.

**How do I repair this snafu?** The damage is already done. I have a backup of the `.git` folder before I did ran the `filter-branch` but I have commits after this backup was made, not many but enough to warrant finding a patch-like fix on the current repo. I don't see any obvious branch-specific arguments to the `filter-branch` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filter-branch will "*rewrite only the positive refs mentioned in the command line*". So you need to specify "--branches" to rewrite all branches. You specified HEAD, so it just rewrote HEAD (i.e. master)

After you run filter-branch, the original refs are backed up in refs/original (i.e. refs/original/master is master before filtering): the objects are still available, and I believe the reflogs are kept intact too, so recovering from a bad filter-branch operation is fairly straightforward.

So your options are:

- Undo the filter-branch command by checking out master and doing `git reset --hard refs/original/master`
- Filter the other branches so they are transformed as well: redo the `filter-branch` command but specify `--branches --not master` instead of HEAD, or more safely by naming the branches to be modified explicity

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct once you explain how recovery is straightforward. If it were straightforward, I would have done it by now. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the OP just needs to rewrite all branches *except* master, so that might be doable in the current repository. Still, I'd probably make a separate clone, put master back where it was (from refs/originals), do `filter-branch --index-filter ... -- --all` to rewrite all refs, and once it all looks okay, grab the commits made after the filter-branch (should be possible with a `rebase --onto`).

Comment: @James Dunne: Either you `reset --hard HEAD@{1}` (according to `reflog`), or you checkout `refs/original/master` and set it as the new, old master branch's HEAD. Then you have restored your original situation and can try again using the `--branches` option in `filter-branch` this time.

Comment: @poke: Except the OP has work on the post-filter master, so it's a little more complicated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of git, so I don't know what to do with 'refs/original/master'. A list of git commands would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Jefromi: It doesn't sound to me that way? @James Dunne: Read my comment again, basically all those are direct commands you can do with git (just add the `git` before); but make sure to backup first and read about the commands...

Comment: @poke: It's a little ambiguous, but he said: "I have a backup of the .git folder before I did ran the filter-branch  but I have commits after this backup was made" - so I assumed the backup was *immediately* before, and therefore the commits were after. Could be mistaken.

Comment: @poke: I have commits in the post-filter master. How do I get those back after I move back to the pre-filter master and re-run the filter-branch correctly applied to all branches? A better solution would be to just re-run the filter-branch with the --branches argument explicitly listing the 8 or so other branch names, no?

Comment: filter-branch isn't a friendly command-- if you're not comfortable poking around with git's innards, rearranging the file hierarchy might be best done by simply moving things around and committing that as a change in each branch. Still, as mentioned, `git reset --hard refs/original/master` when you have master checked out should undo the filter-branch command. Then you can take a backup and try filtering again with the --branches option to migrate all the branches at once. Or you can redo the filter-branch naming the other branches to migrate.

Comment: I made a backup of the entire `.git` folder before I ran the filter-branch, just to be safe. But then after I applied the change all looked good, so I went ahead and made some commits to master after that. Now I realize when I try to checkout one of the old branches, they are wrong. So, yes, I could "restore" that old backup but then I'd have to somehow replay my new changes on top of that. Sounds a bit nasty to me, so I'd rather fix it in-place.

Comment: Don't use "--branches" *and* your other branch names. "--branches" is an alias that expands into "all local branches", i.e. including master as well as the others. I suppose you could say "--branches --not master" though, but better to be explicit.

Comment: @James Dunne: Restore your initial layout, cherry-pick or patch the new commits and do the filter again (on all branches). Or as araqnid said, make the folder change a commit so you don't mess up the whole history (very important if there are other collaborators).

Comment: Thanks, @araqnid. I think it is becoming clearer now. I have a `master` branch and another branch created post-filter that I need to exclude from the filter-branch command I have to run now. My next hurdle is the sed script to run to correctly fix the paths since things have gotten more complicated now.

Comment: One small problem. I see no `--branches` argument for `git-filter-branches`. I have git 1.7.4 under cygwin.

Comment: `git filter-branches` has an argument *<rev-list options>* which basically gets mapped to `git rev-list` (which accepts the `--branches` option). Note however that running on all the other branches might still affect those commits within master *again* when those branches branch-off the master branch at some point. So you might end up with a twice adjusted path for some commits (make sure you respect that in your filter script).

Comment: Right. The documentation for filter-branch assumes the reader already has good familiarity with git concepts and commands, which is one reason I described it as not being very friendly.

Comment: Okay, the --branches approach completely failed. I made a new local working tree with my backed up .git folder and git reset --hard within there to restore a clean tree. Then I did the branch-filer with `-- --all` and that's working great. I have all branches good to go. Now I just need to reapply the 9 new commits from my other local repo. How?