# Git subdirectory filter with existing directory structure

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm splitting out a Git repository using the --subdirectory-filter option of filter-branch which is working great except it pulls everything up to the root of the repository.

I currently have

```
ABC
  - DEF
      - GHI
      - JKL
  - MNO
```

And the result of this command:

```
git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter ABC/DEF --prune-empty -- --all
```

Generates this:

```
GHI
JKL
```

Where what I really want is this:

```
ABC
  - DEF
      - GHI
      - JKL
```

I can't see anything in the Git docs that shows a filter option which preserves (or sets) the directory structure and I haven't been able to find a command I can run *after* the filtering to remap the structure to how I want it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081106/move-git-folder-up-in-working-tree-hierarchy) which does the trick.

The command:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git ls-files -s \
| sed "s-\t-&ABC/DEF/-" \
| GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info \
&& mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE'
```

works perfectly

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too. Thanks for posting it. I should add that this command doesn't replace the `--subdirectory-filter` command; you still execute that. This command replaces the `git mv * ...` command that other documents recommend. But without the ugly massive commit the `git mv` would have generated.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me.  I'm on Windows running git-bash, and it fails saying it can't find index.new ($GIT_INDEX_FILE.new).  I wish I could use this solution.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch $GIT_INDEX_FILE is an environment variable which most tools I've used sets for you;  Both MsysGit and CygWin along with several git bash for Windows alternatives. What's your exact setup?

Comment: It's using bit-bash on windows.  It's not behaving like a full unix system would.

Comment: On Windows git-bash, this appears to create a new subdirectory ("ABC/DEF") and then move all the files into that subdirectory, so instead of "ABC/DEF/GHI" you end up with "ABC/DEF/", which contains the existing repository, having moved everything into that subdirectory while removing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I've only given this cursory testing myself, but I think you can use `git filter-branch` with `--tree-filter` to rewrite the branch, but removing all files apart from those in the subdirectory `ABC/DEF`, with something like the following:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter \
    'find . -path ./ABC/DEF -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f' \
    --prune-empty HEAD
```

Note that the `find` command only removes files, not directories, but since git doesn't store empty directories, this should still produce the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. With the size of this repository I really need something that works off the index (index-filter rather than tree-filter). Your answer is definitely on the right track but would have been very slow in my situation. I found an answer but I'm not sure of the etiquette of accepting my own answer when this would probably suit most cases.

Comment: [Answering your own question is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and if it's the answer that solved your question you should accept it too.  You have to [wait 48 hours](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) though.  The `--tree-filter` version command I tested above was indeed pretty slow, but typically with filter-branch it's a one-off thing, so I wouldn't care if I had to leave it going overnight...

Comment: This is the only answer I could find that a) Left the existing directory structure intact and b) Actually filtered out everything that wasn't in the target directory. It took ages, but when I asked it to filter "/ABC", I actually had "/ABC/file.name", not "/file.name" or "/ABC/ABC/file.name", and that's all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
git filter-branch -f --to-subdirectory-filter ABC/DEF --prune-empty -- --all
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is recommended to give an explaination for what it is doing and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

2020+: A better option, considering [`git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309) are obsolete after Git 2.22 (Q4 2019) or more, is to use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)):

```
git filter-repo --path ./ABC/DEF
```

That will preserve the directory structure.

Note: `git filter-repo` will [force you to make a backup first](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#FRESHCLONE), then proceed to change the history of the local repository you are filtering.