# git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Is there a way to `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` without moving the subdirectory to the root?

I've been rebasing the initial commit to move them back, but it's a pain and doesn't get everything when files are added later.  Overall it's not a good method.

I also have found [Git subdirectory filter with existing directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383117/git-subdirectory-filter-with-existing-directory-structure) but it's accepted solution feels hackish / dangerous to me.

Comment: Are you dead set against using `--tree-filter`?  (It's very slow but `--tree-filter` would make it easy to get the result you want.)  Alternatively, you could use an `--index-filter` that removes everything not in the subdirectory, but this is a bit trickier.

Comment: I gave it a try but our repo is so large that it is going to take *hours*.

Comment: Well, https://xkcd.com/974/ ... but: once you have a tree-filter that works, you can convert it to an index-filter that does the same thing.  Using an index filter is much faster since it allows git to avoid the checkout / rebuild steps.  Basically you replace actual `rm`s with `git rm --cached`, and instead of reading the work tree, you read the git tree associated with the commit the index filter is filtering (using `git ls-tree`).